# jQuery. Check onload if checkbox is checked and add css to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, checkbox, show-hide

MY PROBLEM

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

if ($('input.pokazkontakt').prop(':checked')) {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.pkbox:first').css('display', 'block');
} else {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.pkbox:first').css('display', 'none');
}

$('input.pokazkontakt').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().nextAll('.pkbox:first').toggle('fast');
});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/wgrRd/1/)

2nd part of JS is working (toogle), but i want to check first if checkbox is checked and hide the div or show. Where is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

    $('input.pokazkontakt').each(function(){
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).parent().nextAll('.pkbox:first').css('display', 'none');
        } else {
            $(this).parent().nextAll('.pkbox:first').css('display', 'block');    
        }
    });

    $('input.pokazkontakt').click(function () {
        $(this).parent().nextAll('.pkbox:first').toggle('fast');
    });
});
```

- Use your logic reversely when you set `display:none` and `display:block`.
- Use `.is` to check for checked state.
- Use `.each` to iterate all your checkboxes

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wgrRd/4/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
if($('input.pokazkontakt').is(':checked'))
```

instead of  `if($('input.pokazkontakt').prop(':checked'))`

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wgrRd/2/)

Comment: Your demo doesn't work. The divs are still visible with 2nd and 3rd checkboxs checked.